# Is it possible to load a list of xml-urls with XmlDocument? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm doing a MVC application where several Xml-files will be used (Every XML-file has the same nodes and DTD). I'm wondering if it is possible to use the .Load-method to load a list containing strings of XML-files?

If not, is there any other solution for loading several Xml-files at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first load all the XML files from a folder and then create a list of xmldocuments from the file list:

```
var filePathsList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.xml");
var xmlDocuments = new List<XmlDocument>(filePathsList.Count());
foreach (var filePath in filePathsList)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
    xmlDocuments.Add(xmlDoc);
}
```

You will then have the xmlDocuments list filled with your XMLs.